# Format sparse json files for legibility

Tags: formatting, filetype-json

## Situation

I have a large, hierarchical json file with many single entries, like so:

```json
       {
          "tokens": [
            "payload, a string"
          ],
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "frong zshok blam flarb"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "tokens": [
            "another token"
          ],
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "another important string"
            }
          ]
        },
```

so there are lots of empty lines with brackets and parentheses.

## Question:

How can I have json formatted to only use line breaks after `:` or `,`?

What I'm hoping for is something like this:

```json
{ "tokens": 
    [ "<foo.barbaz>" ],
  "values": 
    [ { "value": "<frong gronk shoop blurb>" } ] },
{ "tokens": 
    [ "<a string>" ],
      "values": 
    [ { "value": "<another string>" } ] },
```

Pretty indentation to have contents of [] {} () aligned would be a bonus.

Whether this is done via external tool or vim plugin, I wouldn't mind either.

Comment: if you know of a tool that formats a json like this, you can filter your buffer using this tool

Comment: Is your actual file as regularly structured/formatted as your example?

Comment: @Rich, yes, that's a copy/paste with replaced values

Comment: Not a solution, but a worthy alternative: I have found that I can use a json2yaml script and can now use a much more convenient format.

[-2 urgency]

Comment: I wonder if using a racket-like formatter would work, since it sees all 3 types of brackets as parens.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do with a series of substitutions:

1. First, add a newline after every `:` or `,`:

   ```
   :%s/[:,]/&\r
   ```
2. Then replace any newline that *doesn't* follow a `:` or `,` with a single space.

   ```
   :%s/[^:,]\zs\n\s*/ /
   ```
3. Then, note that you don't actually want newlines between `:` and `"` characters, so replace these with single spaces too:

   ```
   :%s/:\_s*"/: "
   ```
4. Finally, fix the indents, and remove any completely blank lines that have been introduced:

   ```
   =gg
   :g/^$/d
   ```

You could probably do all this with only two substitutions or perhaps even just one, but the regular expressions would be a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Because the structure of your file is so regular, you can do this very quickly with a recursive macro.

Starting with your cursor at the top of the file (`gg`), type in the following:

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>
<kbd>J</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>
<kbd>J</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>
<kbd>6</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>
<kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

#### How it works

1. <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> This is recursive macro boilerplate. It clears out the `"q` register and then starts recording a macro into it.
2. <kbd>J</kbd> Join the next line.
3. <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> Move the cursor to the colon.
4. <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> Add a newline and some indent.
5. <kbd>J</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> Join the next two lines.
6. <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> Move the cursor to the next line and then to the colon.
7. <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> Add another newline and indent.
8. <kbd>6</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> Join the next 6 lines.
9. <kbd>+</kbd> Move to the next line. We're now done formatting.
10. <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> This is more recursive macro boilerplate. The first <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> plays back the macro in register `"q`, but that register is currently empty because we cleared it in step 1. Then the <kbd>q</kbd> stops the recording and saves the macro. Finally, the <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> plays back the recursive macro. The macro will continue playing back until it hits the bottom of the file.